# Valor undefined na última iteração para percorrer array aninhado

Tags: javascript, array

Eu fiz o seguinte código com intenção de percorrer o seguinte array:

```
[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]
```

Tudo está ocorrendo como eu queria, todos os valores do array estão sendo exibidos mas o último `console.log` retorna `undefined`, eu não sei o porquê. O código a seguir:

```js
let vet = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

function showNums(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
}
  
console.log(showNums(vet));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua função não retorna nenhum valor (não tem nenhum `return` dentro dela). [E nesses casos, o "retorno" da mesma é `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description). Ex

```js
function comReturn() {
    console.log('eu retorno um valor');
    return 1;
}
function semReturn() {
    console.log('eu não retorno nada');
}

let x = comReturn();
let y = semReturn();

console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // undefined
```

Ou seja, a função `showNums` retorna `undefined`, e como você mandou imprimir o retorno dela, o `undefined` é impresso ao final.

Sendo assim, bastaria chamar a função, sem imprimir o retorno:

```js
let vet = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

function showNums(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
}

showNums(vet);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, minha dúvida foi sanada com sucesso!

Comment: @Saul44 Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema :-)

Comment: Estou tentando aceitar, o site pede que eu espere no mínimo 5 minutos, mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @Saul44 Ah é, esqueci que tem esse tempo de espera pra aceitar... :-)